# Selenium Is returning error No such Element: Unable to locate the element

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

I am trying to Web scrape Indeed Jobs using both selenium and beautiful soup, I am able to extract all the details from the Job but to get the Job description I have used Selenium, But when I am trying to find the Job-description Id it's returning the error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="jobDecriptionText"]"}
(Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.75)

I have used the following code:

```
for jobs in analyst_jobs:
get_html = jobs.get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'jobTitle'}).text
print(title)
company = soup.find('span', {'class': 'companyName'}).text
print(company)
location = soup.find('div', {'class': 'companyLocation'}).text
print(location)
desc = soup.find('div', {'class': 'job-snippet'}).text
print(desc)
summary = jobs.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "job_seen_beacon")[0]
summary.click()
jd = driver.find_element(By.ID, "jobDecriptionText")
print(jd)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: Unable to locate element. Selenium may work faster before the element is located. You can use "wait" to wait until your element is located. For more, you can see: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

So you can do that as follows:

```
#import necessary parts for wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#..your code for webdriver

#set wait to make it easy to use
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 
#your other codes... 

#finally, you can use wait like this:
jd = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 
"jobDecriptionText")))
print(jd)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening when **no such element exception** is thrown

1. Incorrect locator - Please check if you are using correct CSS/Xpath.
2. WebElement is not yet loaded - You need to add wait for the element to be interactable.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding in the Furkan answer, you can use the below one as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#..your code for webdriver

#set wait to make it easy to use
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 
#your other codes... 

#finally, you can use wait like this:
jd = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 
"jobDecriptionText")))
print(jd)
```